# Trying to get two traffic lights operating in sequence

Tags: javascript, html, state-machine

I have an application that I have written that adds a set of traffic lights on the screen upon the press of a button. The traffic light automatically cycles from red to yellow after 10 seconds, then on to green after two seconds, then back to yellow after 10 seconds and finally back to red. I would like to add several of these traffic lights to the screen and have them operating at the same time, but when I add a second traffic light, the first traffic light's sequence is frozen at whatever state it has reached. Any ideas as to how to get it to continue to operate - and thus have more than one light cycling through the sequence at the same time?

The transition is controlled by javascript via a state machine.

Anyone have any ideas as to how to get this working smoothly?

Thanks!

Rob

London, UK

```js
var i = 1;
var TrafficLight = function(i) {
  var count = 0;

  var light_container = document.getElementById('light-container-' + i);
  var currentState = new Red(this, light_container);

  this.change = function(state) {
    currentState = state;
    currentState.go();
  }

  this.start = function() {
    currentState.go();
  }

}

var Red = function(light, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#d8412c';
    console.log(light_container);
    setTimeout(function() {
      light.change(new Yellow(light, 'red', light_container))
    }, 10000);
  }
}

var Yellow = function(light, origin, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#fad201';
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (origin == 'red') {
        light.change(new Green(light, light_container));
        light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
        light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
      } else if (origin == 'green') {
        light.change(new Red(light, light_container));
        light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
}

var Green = function(light, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#33A532';
    setTimeout(function() {
      light.change(new Yellow(light, 'green', light_container))
      light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
    }, 10000);
  }
};


function run() {

  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<div id="light-container-' + i + '"><div class="outer-circle-red"><div id="inner-circle-red"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-yellow"><div id="inner-circle-yellow"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-green"><div id="inner-circle-green"></div></div></div>';

  var light = new TrafficLight(i);

  light.start();
  i++;
}
```

```css
.outer-circle-red,
.outer-circle-yellow,
.outer-circle-green {
  background-color: #696969;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: table;
}

#light-container-1,
#light-container-2,
#light-container-3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

#inner-circle-red,
#inner-circle-yellow,
#inner-circle-green {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #111111;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  background-color: #111111;
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="button" onclick="run()">+ Add a new traffic light</div>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: But the ids are unique as for each new traffic light I am creating, I am using a unique id for the container ('light container 1, light container 2') etc. Then when changing the actual traffic light itself, I referencing the parent id, i.e. "light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-green')" refers to .light-container-2 .inner-circle-green...could this still be an issue?

Comment: Yep that'll be an issue.  One approach is to use classes instead of ids which will work in querySelector like `light_container.querySelector(".inner-circle-green")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is, as Lewis already stated that you have multiple elements with the same `id`. JavaScript can only handle one of those.

The other issue is that you delete the content of `#container` by using `innerHTML`. The references you have stored in your `TrafficLight`, `Red`, `Yellow`, and `Green` classes is then destroyed. The store works correctly, but it can't be seen so. Use the DOM manipulation instead.

```
  var light_container = document.createElement('div');
  light_container.id = "light-container-" + i;
  light_container.innerHTML = '<div class="outer-circle-red"><div class="inner-circle-red"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-yellow"><div class="inner-circle-yellow"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-green"><div class="inner-circle-green"></div></div>';
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(light_container);
```

```js
var i = 1;
var TrafficLight = function(i) {
  var count = 0;

  var light_container = document.getElementById('light-container-' + i);
  var currentState = new Red(this, light_container);

  this.change = function(state) {
    currentState = state;
    currentState.go();
  }

  this.start = function() {
    currentState.go();
  }

}

var Red = function(light, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#d8412c';
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      light.change(new Yellow(light, 'red', light_container))
    }, 10000);
  }
}

var Yellow = function(light, origin, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#fad201';
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (origin == 'red') {
        light.change(new Green(light, light_container));
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
      } else if (origin == 'green') {
        light.change(new Red(light, light_container));
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
}

var Green = function(light, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#33A532';
    setTimeout(function() {
      light.change(new Yellow(light, 'green', light_container))
      light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
    }, 10000);
  }
};


function run() {
  var light_container = document.createElement('div');
  light_container.id = "light-container-" + i;
  light_container.innerHTML = '<div class="outer-circle-red"><div class="inner-circle-red"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-yellow"><div class="inner-circle-yellow"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-green"><div class="inner-circle-green"></div></div>';
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(light_container);

  var light = new TrafficLight(i);

  light.start();
  i++;
}
```

```css
.outer-circle-red,
.outer-circle-yellow,
.outer-circle-green {
  background-color: #696969;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: table;
}
[id^=light-container] {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.inner-circle-red,
.inner-circle-yellow,
.inner-circle-green {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #111111;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  background-color: #111111;
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="button" onclick="run()">+ Add a new traffic light</div>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @yunzen, thanks for your reply - please view my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine it's because you aren't using unique #IDs. Here's an example from your code;

> `light_container.querySelector('#inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor`

If there's more than one `#inner-circle-red` on the page, you'll see errors like this. Perhaps try and be more specific with your selectors - like this;

```
#light-container-1 .inner-circle-red
#light-container-2 .inner-circle-red
```

I also added a couple of variables and a loop to help manage multiple lights;

```
   for(let i = 1; i <= lights; i++){
      var light = new TrafficLight(i);
      light.start();
   }
```

See the snippet below for all changes;

```js
var lights = 0;

var TrafficLight = function(i) {
  var count = 0;

  var light_container = document.getElementById('light-container-' + i);
  var currentState = new Red(this, light_container);

  this.change = function(state) {
    currentState = state;
    currentState.go();
  }

  this.start = function() {
    currentState.go();
  }

}

var Red = function(light, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#d8412c';
    console.log(light_container);
    setTimeout(function() {
      light.change(new Yellow(light, 'red', light_container))
    }, 10000);
  }
}

var Yellow = function(light, origin, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#fad201';
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (origin == 'red') {
        light.change(new Green(light, light_container));
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
      } else if (origin == 'green') {
        light.change(new Red(light, light_container));
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
}

var Green = function(light, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#33A532';
    setTimeout(function() {
      light.change(new Yellow(light, 'green', light_container))
      light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
    }, 10000);
  }
};


function run() {  
   lights++;
   
          document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<div id="light-container-' + lights + '"><div class="outer-circle-red"><div class="inner-circle-red"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-yellow"><div class="inner-circle-yellow"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-green"><div class="inner-circle-green"></div></div></div>';
   
   for(let i = 1; i <= lights; i++){
      var light = new TrafficLight(i);
      light.start();
   }
}
```

```css
.outer-circle-red,
.outer-circle-yellow,
.outer-circle-green {
  background-color: #696969;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: table;
}

#light-container-1,
#light-container-2,
#light-container-3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.inner-circle-red,
.inner-circle-yellow,
.inner-circle-green {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #111111;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  background-color: #111111;
}

#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="button" onclick="run()">+ Add a new traffic light</div>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: This is partly true. Your code works unless you add a new TrafficLight. All the TrafficLights are newly started then

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your answer. Just as an extra feature I have added a control which allows the user to start each traffic light individually. I am trying to figure out how to enable the user to permanently stop each traffic light, without it stopping all the others.

Here is my updated code so far - note the addition of the 'this.stop()' function inside of var Red. I would like the code to stop the rotation there, rather than continue to yellow and green.

Thanks,

Rob

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Traffic Lights</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #button {
            width: 200px;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: #ffffff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .button {
            width: 15px;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: red;
            color: #ffffff;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 20px auto;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .outer-circle-red, .outer-circle-yellow, .outer-circle-green {
            background-color: #696969;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 50px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: table;
        }
        .light-container {
            margin: 20px 30px 0 30px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            float: left;
        }
        .inner-circle-red, .inner-circle-yellow, .inner-circle-green {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            border: 2px solid #111111;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 7.5px;
            background-color: #111111;
        }
        /* The switch - the box around the slider */
        .switch {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 60px;
          height: 34px;
          margin-top: 20px;
        }

        /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
        .switch input {
          opacity: 0;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
        }

        /* The slider */
        .slider {
          position: absolute;
          cursor: pointer;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: #ccc;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
        }

        .slider:before {
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          height: 26px;
          width: 26px;
          left: 4px;
          bottom: 4px;
          background-color: white;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
        }

        input:checked + .slider {
          background-color: #2196F3;
        }

        input:focus + .slider {
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
        }

        input:checked + .slider:before {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
          -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
          transform: translateX(26px);
        }

        /* Rounded sliders */
        .slider.round {
          border-radius: 34px;
        }

        .slider.round:before {
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="button" onclick="initiate()">+ Add a new traffic light</div>

    <div id="container">        

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 1;
        var TrafficLight = function (i) {
            var count = 0;

            var light_container = document.getElementById('light-container-' + i);
            var currentState = new Red(this, light_container);

            this.change = function (state) {
                currentState = state;
                currentState.go();
            }

            this.start = function () {
                currentState.go();
            }

            this.stop = function () {
                currentState.stop();
            }

        }

        var Red = function (light, light_container) {
            this.light = light;

            this.go = function () {
                light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#d8412c';
                console.log(light_container);
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    light.change(new Yellow(light, 'red', light_container))                 
                }, 12000);                  
            }

            this.stop = function () {
                light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
                light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
                light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
                // Switch all the lights off.
                return;
            }
        }

        var Yellow = function (light, origin, light_container) {
            this.light = light;

            this.go = function () {
                light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#fad201';
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    if(origin == 'red'){
                        light.change(new Green(light, light_container));
                        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
                        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
                    } else if(origin == 'green'){
                        light.change(new Red(light, light_container));
                        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
                    }
                }, 2000);   
            }
        }

        var Green = function (light, light_container) {
            this.light = light;
            console.log('here');
            this.go = function () {
                light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#33A532';
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    light.change(new Yellow(light, 'green', light_container))
                    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
                }, 14000);   
            }
        };


        function initiate(){
            var light_container = document.createElement('div');
            light_container.id = "light-container-" + i;
            light_container.className = "light-container";
            light_container.innerHTML = '<div class="outer-circle-red"><div class="inner-circle-red"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-yellow"><div class="inner-circle-yellow"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-green"><div class="inner-circle-green"></div></div><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" class="off" onclick="toggleRun(this, ' + i + ');"><span class="slider round"></span></label>';
                document.getElementById("container").appendChild(light_container);
            i++;
        }

        function toggleRun(item, i){
            if(item.className == "off"){
                item.className="on";
                run(i);
            } else {
                item.className="off";
                stop(i);
            }
        }
        function run(i){

            var light = new TrafficLight(i);

            light.start();

        }
        function stop(i){
            var light = new TrafficLight(i);
            light.stop();
        }
        function exit( status ){   

            var i;

            if (typeof status === 'string') {
                alert(status);
            }

            window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();}, false);

            var handlers = [
                'copy', 'cut', 'paste',
                'beforeunload', 'blur', 'change', 'click', 'contextmenu', 'dblclick', 'focus', 'keydown', 'keypress', 'keyup', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseout', 'mouseover', 'mouseup', 'resize', 'scroll',
                'DOMNodeInserted', 'DOMNodeRemoved', 'DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument', 'DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', 'DOMAttrModified', 'DOMCharacterDataModified', 'DOMElementNameChanged', 'DOMAttributeNameChanged', 'DOMActivate', 'DOMFocusIn', 'DOMFocusOut', 'online', 'offline', 'textInput',
                'abort', 'close', 'dragdrop', 'load', 'paint', 'reset', 'select', 'submit', 'unload'
            ];



            function stopPropagation (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                // e.preventDefault(); // Stop for the form controls, etc., too?
            }
            for (i=0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
                window.addEventListener(handlers[i], function (e) {stopPropagation(e);}, true);
            }

            if (window.stop) {
                window.stop();
            }

            throw '';
            }

    </script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Please post this as a new question